# Map Hibernate Column in Many-To-One Mapping and as a Property

Tags: java, hibernate

In my DeviceAttributes.hbm.xml file I want to do the following:

```
    <property
    name="deviceId"
    type="java.lang.String"
    not-null="true"
    column="DeviceID"
    unique="true"
    length="32">
    <meta attribute="field-description">
        @hibernate.property
        column="DeviceID"
        unique="true"
        length="32"
        not-null="true"
    </meta>
</property>

<many-to-one 
    name="device" 
    class="Device" 
    not-null="false" 
    property-ref="deviceId">
    <meta attribute="field-description">
        @hibernate.many-to-one
        not-null="true"
        @hibernate.column name="DeviceID"
    </meta>
    <column name="DeviceID" />
</many-to-one>
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: DeviceAttributes column:
>   DeviceID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I understand that I'm getting this error because I have the column "DeviceID" mapped twice; once in the "property" tag and once in "many-to-one" tag.

Is there a way I can map the "DeviceID" column to a JavaBean property AND use it to join the two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to use ORM and objects then why you still want to map just `deviceId` instead of `device` as Many-to-One? You can access `deviceId` field at any time as `deviceAttribute.getDevice().getId()`.
If you still want map device twice, you should decide which one you'll use for writing device attribute, and then add `insert="false" update="false"` attributes in one of device field mapping.

Comment: Thanks. I added `insert="false" update="false"` to the `<many-to-one>` mapping. This way I can directly update the DeviceID attribute of the record.